# (Copy if) Multiple Variables

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy

I wanted to copy data from one sheet to another. The selection part is according to date and specific value of column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjKqx.png)

I tried this code from internet. So the basic logic is if 2 condition are met then copy the row. However its not working.

It actually working first when only one condition are written, when the second one written, the VBA did not do anything

```
Sub CopyRowsAcross()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Clean_Sheet")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily_Report")

For i = 2 To ws1.Range("P65536").End(xlUp).Row
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "DOWNY S.FRESH 900ML"  and ws2.Range ("C2") = ws1.Cells(i,3) Then
    ws1.Rows(i).Copy ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

the ws2.Range("C2") are selected date written in cell C2 in the sheet.

The result are the row copied based on this 2 criteria

Comment: Step thru the code using F8 and inspect the variables - especially the dates.  Are you sure they are in the same format?

Comment: Tried `CDate(ws2.Range("C2")) = CDate(ws1.Cells(i,3))`? Note this is comparing to the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This works assuming both your data in worksheet 1 are really dates and the filter in C2 is a date also:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyRowsAcross()

    Dim LastRow As Long, lrow As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Clean_Sheet")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily_Report")
    Dim DateFilter As Date

    With ws2
        DateFilter = .Cells(2, 3)
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    With ws1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:C" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="DOWNY S.FRESH 900ML"
        .Range("A1:C" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Format(DateFilter, "dd-Mmm-yy")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRow > 1 Then
            .Range("A2:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws2.Cells(lrow, 1)
        End If
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Instead of looping (Time consuming) you could just filter the data you need and copy it all a t once.

Comment: Hi Thank you for replying. It seems theres an error in the range selection as it said "Method range of Object_Worsheet Failed"

Comment: Where exactly is giving you this error @PrasetyaGiri?